# Reuse Select Statement within a Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement

I like to do something like

```
create tmp_table as ( select 1 some_value, 2 some_other_value from dual union select 3 some_value, 4 some_other_value from dual );

insert into table1 (field1) select some_value from tmp_table;

update table2 set field2 = 5 where field1 in ( select some_value from tmp_table );

drop tmp_table;
```

Is there any nicer way of doing that? Maybe an iterative use of a WITH statement?

```
with tmp_statement as (select ...) ( insert... update ... )
```

Edit:

Hi, sorry for the very generic question. Basically, I wanted to improve some company syntax (select..loop...do things here slowly line by line) by splitting the action but keeping the "one select only" rule alive, because the selects are going to be expansive and you want to edit one select only anyways. I tried to use with as it seems closer to the existing syntax. But maybe the functionality to load the select into a temp/private/actual table is just the better way to do it.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: How about keeping the temp table for reuse? There are private temp tables in 19c but they don't really help you in PL/SQL as it needs table definitions at compile time. Alternatively a collection might help.

Comment: try to explain a bit better what you want to achieve. Insert and update can  be combined in a single merge statement where the target table is the same. In your case , it is not possible as you want to insert and update two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a pure SQL solution to reference a value across multiple statements, use a substitution variable (which works in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, sqlcl and any other environment which supports SQL*Plus commands):

```
ACCEPT some_value PROMPT "Please enter a value for SOME_VALUE:"

insert into table1 (field1) select '&&some_value' from dual;

update table2 set field2 = 5 where field1 in ('&&some_value' );
```

---

However, your use of set-based operations suggests you're expecting TMP_TABLE might hold more than one row. The above won't work in that scenario. If this is the case please **edit your question** to provide more details regarding what you're trying to achieve.

There are various solutions to this, which include PL/SQL collections or retaining TMP_TABLE across executions.  It depends on how often you want to do this thing.

The anti-pattern of creating and dropping objects like TMP_TABLE is common amongst developers who come from a T-SQL background. Oracle is different from SQL Server in several regards and this is one of them: it frowns on executing DDL on the fly, as part of some transactional logic.

Probably the approach you need would be to create TMP_TABLE as a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE. This is a **permanent** data structure, but its data is discarded at the end of a transaction (or session). If you choose this approach you would create TMP_TABLE once, then use it whenever you needed it, without dropping at the end of each session. [Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 18c or higher, you can use the new `private temporary tables`

In your specific case, you can create the private table, then make the insert and the update, commit and exit. Private temporary tables can be transaction specific or session specific.

Take in consideration the value of the parameter `PRIVATE_TEMP_TABLE_PREFIX` , which determines the prefix for the name convention

```
create private temporary table ora$ptt_tmp_table on commit drop definition 
as select 1 as some_value from dual  ;          

insert into table1 (field1) select some_value from ora$ptt_tmp_table  ;

update table2 set field2 = 5 where field1 in ( select some_value from  ora$ptt_tmp_table  );

commit ; -- here the private table is dropped automatically
```

Comment: Nice PTT demo, but the OP said "within a procedure" which complicates things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted enough details, so I'll try to list all variants:

1. If you need just few variables, then you have the following options:

   - Substitution variables (&var)
   - PL/SQL variables, different scopes available, for example, local variables, private or public package variables, or even objects
   - Collections: nested tables or varrays, for example:

     - varray: `select * from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('a','b','c'));`
     - nested table: `select * from table(sys.ku$_vcnt('a','b','c'));`
     - nested table of numpairs:

```sql
select * 
from
 table(
   sys.ku$_objnumpairlist(
         ku$_objnumpair(1,2),
         ku$_objnumpair(3,4)));
      NUM1       NUM2
---------- ----------
         1          2
         3          4
```

- Context variables, for example:

```sql
SQL> call DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'var1', 'value1');

Call completed.

SQL> select SYS_CONTEXT('CLIENTCONTEXT', 'var1') as var1 from dual;

VAR1
-----------------
value1
```

2. If you need to store data sets (row sets):

- Global temporary tables (or even Private Temporary Tables (18c+))
- Collections